# Python's "open()" throws different errors for "file not found" - how to handle both exceptions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, filenotfoundexception, ioerror

I have a script where a user is prompted to type a filename (of a file that is to be opened), and if the file doesn't exist in the current directory, the user is prompted again. Here is the short version:

```
file = input("Type filename: ")

...
try:
    fileContent = open(filename, "r")
    ...
except FileNotFoundError:
    ...
```

When I tested my script on my MacOS X in Python 3.3x it worked perfectly fine when I type the wrong filename on purpose (it executes the suite under "expect").

However, when I wanted to run my code
on a Windows computer in Python 3.2x, I get an error that says that  "FileNotFoundError" is not defined. So, Python 3.2 on Windows thinks "FileNotFoundError" is a variable and the programs quits with an error.

I figured out that Python 3.2 on Windows throws an "IOError" if the input filename is not valid. I tested it on my Linux machine in Python 2.7, and it's also an IOError.

My problem is now, that the code with

```
except "FileNotFoundError":
```

won't run on Windows's Python 3.2, but if I change it to

```
except "IOError":
```

it won't work on my Mac anymore.

How could I work around it? The only way I can think of is to use just
`except`, which I usually don't want.

Comment: This isn't due to Mac/Windows, it's the *version* of Python. I would investigate 3.2/3.3 on OS X as well (and 3.3 on Windows), consult the change logs, and then revise the question/title as appropriate.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

In 3.3, [`IOError` became an alias for `OSError`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/exceptions.html#IOError), and `FileNotFoundError` is a subclass of `OSError`. So you might try

```
except (OSError, IOError) as e:
   ...
```

This will cast a pretty wide net, and you can't assume that the exception is "file not found" without inspecting `e.errno`, but it may cover your use case.

[PEP 3151](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3151/) discusses the rationale for the change in detail.

Comment: also catches `PermissionError` - for a catch all error message - `print('Error:', e.args[1])`

Answer (score 9):

This strikes me as better than a simple `except:`, but I'm not sure if it is the best solution:

```
error_to_catch = getattr(__builtins__,'FileNotFoundError', IOError)

try:
    f = open('.....')
except error_to_catch:
    print('!')
```

Comment: In other news `except:` followed by a comma is grammatically correct, but still seems very odd.

Comment: That's is also a very nice solution. A little bit longer than `except(IOError, OSError):` but therefore more specific

Comment: this is a anti pattern.

Answer (score 7):

So to exactly catch only when a file is not found, I do:

```
import errno
try:
   open(filename, 'r')
except (OSError, IOError) as e: # FileNotFoundError does not exist on Python < 3.3
   if getattr(e, 'errno', 0) == errno.ENOENT:
      ... # file not found
   raise
```

Answer (score 2):

you can catch 2 errors at the same time

`except (FileNotFoundError, IOError):`

I didn't realize that is what you were asking.  I hope there is a more eloquent solution then to manually inspect

```
try:
   error_to_catch = FileNotFoundError
except NameError:
   error_to_catch = IOError
```

`except error_to_catch`

cwallenpoole does this conditional more eloquently in his answer 
`(error_to_catch = getattr(__builtins__,'FileNotFoundError', IOError))`

Comment: Will this work where - *I get an error that says that "FileNotFoundError" is not defined. So, Python 3.2 on Windows thinks "FileNotFoundError" is a variable and the programs quits with an error* - ?

Comment: @pst interesting sorry didn't consider it