# python - specifically handle file exists exception

Tags: python, exception, ioerror

I have come across examples in this forum where a specific error around files and directories is handled by testing the `errno` value in `OSError` (or `IOError` these days ?). For example, some discussion here - [Python's "open()" throws different errors for "file not found" - how to handle both exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15032108/pythons-open-throws-different-errors-for-file-not-found-how-to-handle-b). But, I think, that is not the right way. After all, a `FileExistsError` exists specifically to avoid having to worry about `errno`.

The following attempt didn't work as I get an error for the token `FileExistsError`.

```
try:
    os.mkdir(folderPath)
except FileExistsError:
    print 'Directory not created.'
```

How do you check for this and similar other errors specifically ?

Comment: Assuming you use 2.7, FileExistsError does not exist as a built-in exception in Python. See a full list of built-in exceptions here:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#module-exceptions
It looks to me like you should use something like "IOError" for this.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

According to the code `print ...`, it seems like you're using Python 2.x. [`FileExistsError`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#FileExistsError) was added in Python 3.3; You can't use `FileExistsError`.

Use [`errno.EEXIST`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/errno.html#errno.EEXIST):

```
import os
import errno

try:
    os.mkdir(folderPath)
except OSError as e:
    if e.errno == errno.EEXIST:
        print('Directory not created.')
    else:
        raise
```

Comment: So, with Python 3.3 onwards, I can use FileExistsError. Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of dealing with a race condition when trying to [atomically overwrite an existing symlink](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55740417/5353461):

```
# os.symlink requires that the target does NOT exist.
# Avoid race condition of file creation between mktemp and symlink:
while True:
    temp_pathname = tempfile.mktemp()
    try:
        os.symlink(target, temp_pathname)
        break  # Success, exit loop
    except FileExistsError:
        time.sleep(0.001)  # Prevent high load in pathological conditions
    except:
        raise
os.replace(temp_pathname, link_name)
```

Comment: `except: raise` good stuff :D