# Pythonic exception handling: only catching specific errno

Tags: python, error-handling, errno

I often read that in python "it is easier to ask for forgiveness then for permission", so it is sometimes considered better to use `try except` instead of `if`.

I often have statements like

```
if (not os.path.isdir(dir)):
    os.mkdir(dir).
```

The likely replacement would be

```
try:
    os.mkdir(dir)
except OSError:
    pass.
```

However I would like to be more specific and only ignore the `errno.EEXIST`, as this is the only error that is expected to happen and I have no idea what could happen.

```
try:
    os.mkdir(dir)
except OSError:
    if(OSError.errno != errno.EEXIST):
        raise
    else:
        pass.
```

Seems to do the trick. But this is really bulky and will 'pollute' my code and reduce readability if I need plenty of these code-blocks. Is there a pythonic way to do this in Python 2.X? What is the standard procedure to handle such cases?

edits:

- use raise instead raise OSerror as pointed out by @Francisco Couzo
- I use Python 2.7

Comment: Just do `raise`, not `raise OSError` so you don't lose the context of the exception

Comment: You could just catch `FileExistsError`: `except FileExistsError: pass`

Comment: Dup of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20790580/python-specifically-handle-file-exists-exception

Comment: No need for `else: pass`, that's redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just stumbled across the probably most elegant solution: creating the `ignored` context manager:

```
import errno
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def ignorednr(exception, *errornrs):
    try:
        yield
    except exception as e:
        if e.errno not in errornrs:
            raise
        pass


with ignorednr(OSError, errno.EEXIST):
     os.mkdir(dir)
```

This way I just have the ugly job of creating the context manager once, from then on the syntax is quite nice and readable.

The solution is taken from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OSGv2VnC0go.

Answer (score 0):

This example is for exception `OSError : 17, 'File exists'`

```
import sys
try:
    value = os.mkdir("dir")
except:
    e = sys.exc_info()[:2]
    e = str(e)
    if "17" in e:
        raise OSError #Perform Action
    else:
        pass
```

Just change the number 17 to your exception number. You can get a better explanation at [this link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info).

Comment: I think my question already provides a better answer, it is shorter and doesn't use the explicit number. I read the numbers might differ depending on the system so `errno.EEXIST` is better and also more readable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling it multiple times with different args, put it in a function:

```
def catch(d, err):
    try:
        os.mkdir(d)
    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno != err:
            raise
```

Then call the function passing in whatever args:

```
 catch(, "foo", errno.EEXIST)
```

You could also allow the option of passing passing multiple errno's if you wanted more:

```
def catch(d, *errs):
    try:
        os.mkdir(d)
    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno not in errs:
            raise

catch("foo", errno.EEXIST, errno.EPERM)
```