# How to handle FileNotFoundError when "try .. except IOError" does not catch it?

Tags: python, exception, python-3.x, try-catch

How can I catch an error on python 3? I've googled a lot but none of the answers seem to be working. The file open.txt doesn't exist so it should print e.errno.

This is what I tried now:

This is in my defined function

```
try:
    with open(file, 'r') as file:
        file = file.read()
        return file.encode('UTF-8')
except OSError as e:
    print(e.errno)
```

However I does not print anything when I get this error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test.txt'
```

Comment: unrelated: do not use the same name for different purposes in the same context. Use `text = file.read()` instead. Keep the text as Unicode, do not encode it to bytes unless it is absolutely necessary.

Comment: make sure that you run the right file. Provide the full traceback.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python's "open()" throws different errors for "file not found" - how to handle both exceptions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15032108/pythons-open-throws-different-errors-for-file-not-found-how-to-handle-b)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

`FileNotFoundError` is a subclass of `OSError`, catch that or the exception itself:

```
except OSError as e:
```

Operating System exceptions have been reworked in Python 3.3; `IOError` has been merged into `OSError`. See the [*PEP 3151: Reworking the OS and IO exception hierarchy* section](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-3151-reworking-the-os-and-io-exception-hierarchy) in the What's New documentation.

For more details the [*OS Exceptions* section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#os-exceptions) for more information, scroll down for a class hierarchy.

That said, your code *should still just work* as `IOError` is now an alias for `OSError`:

```
>>> IOError
<class 'OSError'>
```

Make sure you are placing your exception handler in the correct location. Take a close look at the traceback for the exception to make sure you didn't miss where it is actually being raised. Last but not least, you did restart your Python script, right?

Comment: I updated my code, do you see anything that might be wrong? Could it be the fault of the return line?

Comment: @ThomasW: I can't reproduce your issue with that code; it simply prints `2` for me. No, the return line doesn't cause any issues here.

Comment: How did you solve this @ThomasW? I get this sporadically here https://github.com/pypa/pip/blame/master/src/pip/_internal/req/req_tracker.py#L52 using an embedded version of python on linux...

Comment: @crizCraig: 'sporadically', or on specific Python versions? `open()` can throw `OSError` in Python 3.2 or before.

Comment: @crizCraig: in other words, the code there is not properly backwards compatible with Python 2.x; it should use `except (IOError, OSError) as e:`.

Comment: I'm calling pip install via python https://github.com/deepdrive/deepdrive-sim/blob/511275f3edc7d0f121c0cfd4384c4730d6ebe602/Content/Scripts/ensure_requirements.py#L34-L46 @MartijnPieters in Unreal Engine, which only has the interpreter we've explicitly embedded https://github.com/deepdrive/UnrealEnginePython in it, so I'm pretty sure it's always Python 3.6. I say sporadically because it ends up working after a few runs. Not sure if it's stochastic or deterministic yet.

Comment: @crizCraig: 'pretty sure' is not the same as 'absolutely sure', and the page you link to says Python 2.7 is also embedded. What does `sys.version_info` tell you you have?

Answer (score -2):

Change your OSError to (IOError, OSError) that should work.

@Thomas Wagenaar

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. However, this question is 7 years old, and already has an answer :) so its not the best use of your time. Also, your answer has very little information. See the existing answer to this question for an example of an answer that contains supporting information and documentation.