# Except In Python Doesn't Response If File Doesn't Exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, python-3.6

I search for similar file names & want to upload them for user.

My problem is that when I want to use Try/Except to see this files exists, If files exists, Try & Else Blocks works correctly But If file doesn't exists, It doesn't show user the text ... What is the problem ?

```
search = str(args[0])
pattern = re.compile('.*%s.*\.pdf' %search, re.I)
for files in filter(pattern.search, os.listdir('.')):

    try:
        requested_file = open(files, 'rb')
    except IOError:
        bot.sendChatAction(chat_id, 'typing')
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "This File Doesn't Exists") 
    else:  
        bot.sendChatAction(chat_id, 'typing')
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "The File You Needed : " + files)    
        bot.sendChatAction(chat_id, 'upload_document')
        bot.sendDocument(chat_id, requested_file, files)
        requested_file.close()
```

Comment: Why wouldn't the file exist? You got the file name from `os.listdir`, so the file must exist. Are you saying someone deleted the file after the call to `listdir` but before the call to `open`?

Comment: @Rawing First Part :OK, So How should I Check that if the file is not in os.listdir?
Second Part : No, Files Are Consistent ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15032108/ may help

Comment: @GlennRogers Thanks But It didn't help me ...